# How can I replace "." by "," character in real time with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, input, replace

I would like to control when user writes a number in any input with `type="number"` and `step="any"`, in real time, `JavaScript` replaces `.` character by `,` character.

I tried with this code, but it's not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=number,step=any]').replace('.', ',');
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

Comment: What your missing here is an event listener and event handler. You'll need to be able to capture user key strokes, check the character and then call the `.replace()` function. Look at the jQuery documentation for these functions; onchange(), keydown(), and keypress(). One of those should be able to help.

Comment: It is better to use text type, if you want comma...Comma is not allowed at all (at least in Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, inside a input with `type="number"` you cannot enter commas. The number input can accept [floating point numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float), including negative symbols and the `e` or `E` character, but not commas

You should just use a text input

Try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(".", ","));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

As an example, this is what happens when you use an input with `type="number"`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(".", ","));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="number" />
```

Comment: On my desktop chrome, I can type both `,` and `.` on an `<input type="number">`

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos I've just tried on chrome and safari, and I cannot enter `,` .. strange

Comment: I guess it is because of localization. My `navigator.language` returns `ru`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```
$('input[type=number]').keypress(function () {
    $('input[type=number]').val($('input[type=number]').val().replace(/\./g, ','));
});
```